# Where can I find a list of the cases brought to the International Court of Justice?

Tags: international-law, international-court-of-justice

I went to the [ICJ](https://www.icj-cij.org/home) website to look for cases that are being brought to it. But I found only pending and completed cases. Is there a place I can see a list of the cases that are brought to it (even if they are dismissed)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether cases are just dismissed (do you have a specific example in mind?) - they are not accepted based on "Preliminary objections" (a example http://www.icj-cij.org/docket/files/109/10877.pdf where those are raised). If a case is thrown out it looks like this http://www.icj-cij.org/docket/files/26/2157.pdf which can be found within the List of all cases.

Comment: I keep on hearing "stories" that this or that filed a lawsuit or a claim to the ICJ. But I want to read the full text, see who is against who and what.

Answer (score 5):

The World Legal Information Institute maintains a [database of ICJ cases](http://www.worldlii.org/int/cases/ICJ/). The database is updated on a quarterly basis and it seems to include all cases (dismissed or not). For example, it includes [Georgia’s (dismissed) case against Russia regarding South Ossetia and Abkhazia](http://www.haguejusticeportal.net/index.php?id=12527).

Comment: I am not sure if that link has it all. I have been hearing in the news that there were claims against the State of Israel here and there all around 2014, but I cannot find a single one right now. Any ideas?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul If the cases were very recent, you'll probably have to wait for the next update (remember, the database is updated once every three months. Also, it might just be that the claims you've heard about never made it to ICJ. Do you have a specific example?